# it is better save errors code/message in database or in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I'm working on project that the result is variable and multi-language  then I decided use erros codes so I can get the error message in the corresponding language by error code.

the database that I'm using is `sql ce`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the error messages to be shared by other applications (perhaps written in other languages) that use the same database: Use the database.

If you want to provide an interface whereby someone can maintain the list of errors for different languages: Use the database.

Otherwise use resources strings. It's the normal .NET way, so it'll be more familiar to newcomers to the project, and you've got lots of methods for picking the right version for a given language already there.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET the custom is to put translation strings into Resources. You can have one resource file per language / culture.

For more details, see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pradeepkv/MultilingualAppsInNet11282005010748AM/MultilingualAppsInNet.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest database (error code - language - text) : Roy is right,but there is problem with this approach :

- you edit them in visual studio, what if your translator is not a developer ?
- You have to compile / deploy your program every time you change something in your spelling -> :'(
- You can't share it across apps

Comment: Resource files are just XML files. You don't need Visual Studio and you don't need to be a developer to use/modify them.

Comment: @RoyDictus What if MS change their format ? Resources are not supposed to be included in assembly ?

Comment: You are right! So we should not use C# either. What if MS changes the syntax?

Comment: @RoyDictus  Can you tell me how you handle common/global resource file, and how you edit them (i'm not trying to trash talk about your answer, just want to knwo about the possibilities/limitations of this solution) ?